# Godot engine экспорт

Tags: разработка-игр, exe, export, godot, gdscript

Возможно ли в Godot engine сделать експорт в exe, но со спрайтами не в файле exe или pkg, а
в папке с самим exe-шником? Что-бы можно было менять спрайт в файлах игры и он менялся в игре?